# How to determine what reference data service to use in blpapi

Tags: java, bloomberg, blpapi

I'm quite new in using blpapi and I'm still learning.
My main issue is that I'm quite loss when it comes to what reference data service to use when requesting data from bloomberg.

Is there a way to know what reference data I should use for each of the fields I am requesting?
For example, I want to request CP_FILING_DATE. I tried requesting using ReferenceDataRequest and HistoricalDataRequest but it gives me BAD_FLD error.

Comment: In this case the field should be CP_FILING_DT.
You can use the FLDS function on the Bloomberg Terminal to find what fields are applicable to a security type, but not what requests accept them.  Typically fields in white can be used for Subscriptions and fields in amber are for ReferenceDataRequests (and potentially history as well).

Comment: Not sure why the downvotes, it's a legitimate question. True, OP should have omitted first paragraph, but other than that the question is simple, concise and OP wrote down what error they got.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to tell is to go to `FLDS<GO>` on your Bloomberg Terminal, at the bottom, where it says "API:":

- current value available - supports Reference request
- historical values available - supports Historical request

Also, you can subscribe to fields that are written in white on `FLDS<GO>` and you can filter to show only fields that support a certain request in the "Field Type" combo box.

Comment: Thanks @ytoledano. I've always wondered what the "current value available" means since I always see it. Also, I really want to be well-versed with blpapi and the bloomberg terminal. Can you refere me to any good tutorials? Thank you very much!